# Einstein bot combine Question and Utterances

Tags: einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots, chatbot

Good fellows, I'm working on a bot and I have a problem that I can't find the solution. It is that in a branch I have a question with a couple of options, but when the user inserts a text himself to search by intents.

here the problem is that when the user inserts the text himself what he does is to set the variable, and he gets stuck because in the rules he does not find anything similar and he does not search in the intents either.

in short, when I type test3 the only thing it does is to set the variable "test (Text)" but I want it to search for "Utterances" at the same time.

[image]

what I want is that for example in the image, I write "test3", it is assigned directly to the "Customer input" and redirects me to the branch/dialog with the "Utterances".

[image]

Thank you for any help